# How to get file from url in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I want to download text files using python, how can I do so?

I used requests module's `urlopen(url).read()` but it gives me the bytes representation of file.

Comment: try, ``urlopen(url).read().decode()`` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When downloading text files with python I like to use the wget module

```
import wget

remote_url = 'https://www.google.com/test.txt'

local_file = 'local_copy.txt'

wget.download(remote_url, local_file)
```

If that doesn't work try using urllib

```
from urllib import request

remote_url = 'https://www.google.com/test.txt'

file = 'copy.txt'

request.urlretrieve(remote_url, file)
```

When you are using the request module you are reading the file directly from the internet and it is causing you to see the text in byte format. Try to write the text to a file then view it manually by opening it on your desktop

```
import requests

remote_url = 'test.com/test.txt'

local_file = 'local_file.txt'

data = requests.get(remote_url)

with open(local_file, 'wb')as file:
file.write(data.content)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me,  I had to do the following (Python 3):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

data = urlopen("[your url goes here]").read().decode('utf-8')

# Do what you need to do with the data.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple options:

1. For the simpler solution you can use this

   ```
    file_url = 'https://someurl.com/text_file.txt'
    for line in urllib.request.urlopen(file_url):
        print(line.decode('utf-8'))
   ```
2. For an API solution

   ```
    file_url = 'https://someurl.com/text_file.txt'
    response = requests.get(file_url)
    if (response.status_code):
        data = response.text
    for line in enumerate(data.split('\n')):
        print(line)
   ```